# Extra bonus board glitch

Tags: forza-horizon-5

So, for the past few days I have been trying to get all the bonus boards and a few minutes ago I did but the thing is though is that there are 250 boards in total right? well I have the accolade for 50 fast travel boards and all 250 boards, but it says I only have 199 out of 200 xp boards is this a bug or am I actually missing a xp board

Comment: Curious, but what does the number of Barn Finds in your stats say? I noticed awhile back that mine said 15/14. I've been wondering if one of the bonus boards might have a bug that causes it to count for the wrong stat.

Comment: I think your right because my barn finds stat is 16/14 and i have 24/25 5000xp boards, so I think it's just a glitch in the game